# How to install Quartus II version 11.1 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I need Quartus II v 11.1 because I only have cyclone II, IV.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What are "Quartus II" and "cyclone II, IV"? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

1. Download the `sh` file from [here](https://www.altera.com/bin/get-download?swcode=WWW-SWD-QII-WE-111-LNX&l=en)

   ```
   wget https://www.altera.com/bin/get-download?swcode=WWW-SWD-QII-WE-111-LNX&l=en
   ```
2. Make `executable` with:

   ```
   chmod u+x 11.1_quartus_free_linux.sh
   ```
3. open your terminal and run it

   ```
   ./11.1_quartus_free_linux.sh
   ```

Note:

These commands are all run from the same directory, perhaps `/home/$USER/Downloads`

Source:

https://www.altera.com/downloads/software/quartus-ii-we/111.html

**READ THIS FIRST** Installation guide:

https://www.altera.com/literature/manual/quartus_install.pdf

Comment: the instructions are not for the web edition

Comment: the steps that are described I made.
And in the install.txt map.
it's written:

Red Hat Linux-based systems require 32-bit versions of the X libraries
and glibc for the installer to run correctly.

Use 'rpm' or 'yum' to install the following 32-bit packages on Red Hat
Enterprise Linux systems:

Comment: 1) Did you read the installation pdf link I gave, 2) What OS are we talking here Ubuntu or RHEL?

Comment: OS is a Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I looked into your issue I would suggest your use some sort of container or perhaps a VM to install and use, as I discovered it's applies to `Ubuntu Trusty Tahr`. I don't use this software myself so don't know how the guest hardware will work with it. I see a version `15` but ofcourse your lot looking for that version

Comment: If you haven't had a chance to see it yet the above question is in the vote to reopen queue and you can VTR it now.